# mysql - joining count on multiple tables to a query

Tags: mysql

I want to select columns from a table and a count bases on the join of another two table, how can I do it?

this is my count query which I have written:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_review FROM approved_reviews  m, reviews u where 
   m.review_id_=u.id  and u.item_id =? and m.approved=1
```

and I want to join it to

```
select item_id, item_name, item_price from items ?
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select items.item_id, item_name, item_price, COALESCE(t.cnt ,0)         
from items join (
                  SELECT u.item_id , COUNT(*) cnt
                  FROM approved_reviews  m, reviews u 
                  WHERE m.review_id_=u.id and m.approved=1
                  GROUP BY u.item_id 
                ) t on items.item_id = t.item_id
```

Comment: That helps, but it returns NULL when there are no review....is there some way to makt it reurn 0 in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_review, u.item_id FROM approved_reviews  m, reviews u where 
   m.review_id_=u.id  and u.item_id =? and m.approved=1 group by u.item_id) count_sub, 
(select item_id, item_name, item_price from items) item_sub
where item_sub.item_id = count_sub.item_id
```